# Mongo Log Pass User Management Recommended Setup

Tags: mongodb, security

I'm using mongo 3.07 and have a working authentication system, but it seems like I must be doing things a roundabout hacky way. Is there a simpler way to do this, or perhaps better then the following:

1. I run mongod with my mongod.config default, auth is commented out: #auth=true
2. I run mongo, then I do the following, which I believe is necessary to set my authentication method so that log/pass will work:

   db.system.version.remove({}) <== removing current version

   db.system.version.insert({ "_id" : "authSchema", "currentVersion" : 3 })
3. In mongo console, I create my admin user:

   db.createUser(
   {
   user: "siteUserAdmin",
   pwd: "mysecretpassword",
   roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
   }
   )
4. Then I switch databases to my actual db, lets call my db example:

   db.createUser(
   {
   user: "exampleadmin",
   pwd: "mysecretpassword",
   roles: [ { role: "userAdmin", db: "example" }, { role: "readWrite", db: "example" }]
   }
   )
5. I update mongod.config so that auth = true is not commented out.
6. I relaunch mongod.

Again, this is working for me, and I may continue using it, but is this really a "reasonable" way to setup security in Mongo, or am I doing this in a backwards fasion?

Comment: I'm using mongo 3.07 and I in the mongod.conf file I have added "authorization: enabled" as per the documentation at:
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

In #5 you added "auth = true".

However... for whatever reason, if I make any change to the default mongod.conf file, mongod will not start.

Comment: @Rick, I believe I had similar issues with an update to Mongo, I leave the config default and instead use --auth true as a command line option when running sudo service mongod start --auth true.